# HTTPS on dev server - issues

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, https, woocommerce

I copied a live woocommerce site back to the dev server. The live site uses https. So when I tried accessing it on the dev server, it redirected me to the live site. I figured the issue was the .htaccess file. I tried editing it, but the file is encrypted. So I just removed it all together. That stopped the redirecting, and I was able to access the front-end of the dev site. However when I try to access the wp-admin or wp-login.php I get a 404. I also noticed that the broswer changed from http to https. So there's something still trying to make the website run under https.

What I've tried:

1. I deactivated woocommerce plugin (by renaming it) but that didn't
   help.
2. I also searched in the database for instances of https:// but I
   could not find any that related to the website.
3. I also found and removed a cert.html file in the root which I think
   it's related to the https certification, but I still can't access
   the backend.
4. And last, I tried to add a new .htaccess file with the basic
   wordpress permalinks in it, but that just gave 500 server errors.

Can anyone give some pointers where to look? Or what could be causing the browser to use https, instead of http.

Comment: Are you sure the original htaccess file was encrypted? What was the new htaccess file that you tried to use?

Comment: If it wasn't encrypted it was corrupted. I could not be read. It was just numbers. I just added a blank htaccess file, and also tried adding one with basic rewrite.

# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: Can you check permalink settings of Wordpress?

Comment: I can't login. So I can't check them in the admin.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to change your site URL to point to the right place. Since you can't log in (it'll redirect you to the wrong site URL), you need to change this in your wp-config.php file (see [this link for more info](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)):

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

After that, and hopefully with the default wordpress rules, you should be able to log in to the admin pages.

```
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule> 
# END WordPress
```

The above assumes that your wordpress site is at `/`.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I tried both using the define in the wp-config page and also tried adding the update_options function in functions.php. The URL is not being redirect, execept that's using https. I had already previously gone through the database and removed all instances of https and replaced it with http.